# Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC) in Firefox 3.5+

Tags: css, firefox, base64, concatenation, fouc

We've reached the end of our tether here trying to overcome a nasty and intermittent FOUC in Firefox 3.5.x+ for a new release we're working on.

We've tried:

- Disabling Javascript in FF
- Using Quirks mode rendering by removing the DOCTYPE
- Moving from `@import` for additional CSS to `<link>`
- Switching concatenation on and off
- Removing CSS files from the concat, one at a time
- Switching the local cache off in Firefox
- etc

Our previous release never exhibited any FOUC issues, so it's something we've done to this release.  Changes we've made so far include:

- Using Base64 encoded images over Data URIs for all decorative imagery, served via CSS.
- Separating 'framework'-related CSS files from page-specific CSS and bundling them as two separate CSS files

To recreate the problem... use Firefox 3.5.x or 3.6.x, then:

1. Head on over to: http://my.publisher-subdomain.env.yola.net/
2. Login with username: 'stack@yola.com' and password: 'stackoverflow'
3. Once logged-in, you should be at http://my.publisher-subdomain.env.yola.net/sites/
4. Click the Account link in the main nav.
5. The Account page should load, and you should see a FOUC. If the FOUC does not occur, clear your cache and reload the page.

Your help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**UPDATE:**

The dev environment is still exhibiting the FOUC, but only if FireFox is running low on memory or has a lot of extensions installed.  Latency and rendering speed definitely affect the visibility of this FOUC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9823468/888177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be wrong, but this could be a concurrent connections issue. According to my Firebug's "Net" tab

[image]

the HTML page simply takes a lot of time to load - maybe also because it is on a development server? - and the style sheet gets loaded after the HTML page.

I can't claim to entirely understand what's happening here, but I would try putting the style sheet onto a different domain as a first measure. That should make Firefox establish a connection straight away.

It would probably also be a good idea to go back to normal images instead of data: URIs - that would reduce the size of the style sheet, and data: URIs won't work at all in IE < 8.

Comment: Hey Pekka - yeah, we're running off a dev server in this case.We serve an MHTML file to IE7 which contains the same base64 images.  It works really well.

Comment: @ndorfin yeah, it's not the root of the problem. It just makes the style sheet a bit bigger than usual. I would try putting it on a different domain, maybe that works

Comment: While your answer didn't answer the problem at hand directly, you were the only one to respond, so I'll give you the points :)

Comment: @ndorfin All right. Too bad it didn't get fixed! Very strange, this.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is a very old question, I found it when I was searching for a solution to the same problem.  So, I wanted to post the solution for future reference.  I just needed to move the reference to my CSS files above the references to external Javascript that needed to be in my header.

Comment: Thanks! All my js was at the bottom of the page, except modernizr which was at the top of the header - moving it below the styles worked.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks a lot. This saved me from having to dig through a bunch a hack solutions.

Comment: I'll add in here, that this applies to **any** script tags. Even if it is local code, and not fetching any external files.