# Page is damaged during page loading process

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-easyui

I use jquery easyui to create a datagrid. Why when the page loaded always bring up the damaged page first, like the following picture:

[image]

After that (about 1 second) the display returns to normal page.

[image]

Can anyone explain about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I think it is taking time to load either your CSS or your JS file. If its a problem with the CSS file, once the file has been loaded the styles get applied. If your JS file takes time to load then only after it has finished loading and is run does the plugin initialise your datagrid.

So it seems like basically a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) problem.

You could try the solutions here and see if any solve your problem:
[Eliminate flash of unstyled content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221561/eliminate-flash-of-unstyled-content)