# Doesn't see the CSS on first enter in my codes

Tags: html, css, laravel

I am using Laravel php. Head and Footer tags are in my app.blade file.But it doesn't run the preloader in the head tag when it's first opened. It also doesn't load the css file. It comes after 1-2 seconds exactly. It's too fast to take a screenshot, so I uploaded it as a video. I will add the lines of code below along with the video.

https://youtu.be/ihHmQBsSpNs

app.blade.php header codes:

````
@if(!isset($lang)) @php($lang = 'tr') @endif
@php($slug = Request::segment(1))
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>  
<title>NovaPia Clinic</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="NovaPia Clinic">
<meta name="keywords" content="Dentist, Clinic">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
 
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/style.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/responsive.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/animate.css')}}"/>
    

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('theme/img/favico.png')}}">    


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/icon-fonts/fontawesome-5.0.6/css/fontawesome-all.min.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/icon-fonts/flaticon/flaticon.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/icon-fonts/flaticon/flaticon.svg')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/icon-fonts/flaticon/flaticon.ttf')}}"/>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/40e15e0d0d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/font/stylesheet.css')}}"/>
   

</head> 
<body> 


<div id="preloader">
  <div class="loading-area">
    <div class="logo" style=""><img src="{{ asset('theme/img/nova.png')}}" alt=""></div>
    <span>yükleniyor...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>

<div class="page-overlay">
    <div class="page-transition"></div>
  </div>
<main>


  
  <header class="whitev">
 
    <a href="index.html" class="logo" data-type="ajax-load">
      <img src="{{ asset('img/nova.svg')}}" alt="">
    </a>

    <div class="nav-icon">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      </div>
  </header>```
````

Comment: It's called FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Contents).

Comment: in inspect see Network tab and refresh do you see error or warning ?

Comment: Merging all css files into one may solve the problem.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221561/eliminate-flash-of-unstyled-content. Your problem is, the CSS take time to load, but your contents are already showing. Try to reduce the size of CSS as well as applying the preloader correctly (hide the contents first). What are the contents of the `#preloader` CSS?

Comment: @hashemsheikhypour No. I don't see any error.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Moreover, you can move all the JavaScript to the end of the body.

Comment: @Raptor There is a lot of javascript code.

Comment: I mean the `<script>` tag. It is a good practice to move the scripts before the line of `</body>`.

Comment: @Raptor I tried now but the same problem still persists. I tried the script tags in the FOUC methods and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add display:none in the body, and add a setTimeout to change the display value to block after 5 seconds for example, like that :

```
<body style="display:none" id="body_id">

<script>setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById('body_id').style.display = 'block'; }, "5000");</script>
```

Comment: Don't use a meaningless fixed time. You can always detect whether the contents are loaded or not using JavaScript.

Comment: @Raptor yes you right

Comment: That solve but i have i small problem. [I add your code but it looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/YC2v5uW) <br> [normally it should be like this](https://imgur.com/a/zphxh3s). Below is the line of code I added. `
     <body style="display:none" id="body_id">
    <script>setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById('body_id').style.display = 'block'; }, "4000");</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/style.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/responsive.css')}}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme/css/animate.css')}` @Raptor

Comment: @canswartz the picture link is wrong