# check if javascript is available and redirect if javascript is not available

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

In my php application i need to check whether the javascript is turn on or not in browser. I have tried this `<noscript><p>javascript is off<p></noscript>` it's working fine.But i need to redirect to a page if javascript is OFF so developed like this

```
<noscript>
<?php header('Location: index.php');?>
</noscript>
```

But i/ts always redirecting to index.php, there is any way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your solution clearly cannot work, since php is executed before the page is served on client

you could instead do something like

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">
</noscript>
```

in the head of your document

Answer (score 3):

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=error.html"></noscript>
```

try this to redirect if JS is disabled

Php script runs independently of js

Answer (score 2):

There are known [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170484/shouldnt-we-use-noscript-tag) with **noscript**

Instead do this:

```
<html>

<head>

<script>
window.location.href="javascriptEnabled.html";
/*Since javascript is enabled redirect to javascript based page*/
</script>

</head>

<body>
Showing Static Website since javascript is not enabled..
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a good way to do it, because without client side interactivity, you can not get information back from the client.

You could do something like this...

1. Set up a meta redirect to trigger after 5 seconds
2. use javascript to override the meta redirect

Therefore, if javasccript is enabled, you get to the javascript page, otherwise the non javascript page

Answer (score 0):

It does redirect to index.php because the `<?php header('Location: index.php');?>` is processed by the server while the `<noscript>` is processed by the client ..

A correct way to do this is to set a cookie using javascript on the client, then check for the cookie's presence with php on the server, If the cookie does exist, then javascript is on, Else, it's off.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different approach here

- Use the no javascript version as default version
- Use a javascript redirect to the enhanced version

Remember it's better to not have separate versions of the site. You could progressive enhancement with libraries as http://modernizr.com/ or https://github.com/filamentgroup/enhance