# jQuery: remove containees as soon as they are loaded

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a single-page website with some divs. These divs contain some content, for example an iframe. This content is the fall back text if js/jquery is not available. Now I would like to remove some of the content of these divs, as soon as they are ready, to replace it with some dynamically created content.

Example:
A div containing an iframe for a google calendar. This iframe shall be replaced by the generated content of a $.getJson call of the same calendar.

How do I do that? Is

```
$('div#calendar').ready(function(){ 
  $('div#calendar').remove('iframe')
});
```

early enough? Where should the `script` tag for jquery go, at the moment it's at the end of the body?

Comment: "Where should the script tag for jquery go, I come at the of body at the moment?", that last sentence makes your question unclear. The script tag for jQuery should go in the head section.

Comment: I also use Bootstrap for the layout, they recommend to load jquery at the end to speed up the loading time of the page. That is just how it is now, but I don't see a problem in changing it.

Comment: This is not a good approach. Because users will probably see the content for just an instance, before it is removed/replaced.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) for instances where there is absolutely no JS available.

```
<script src="url"></script>
<noscript>
  <!-- Your iFrame -->
</noscript>
```

If you want more control, have a look at the feature detection approach with for example [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Or have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170484/shouldnt-we-use-noscript-tag) for some thoughts on using or not using the noscript tag or alternative approaches. The most favoured approach seems to be having a `display:none;` block, which is then set to `display:block;` by JS, and vice versa for the non-JS page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `$('div#calendar').html(<new content>)` in your success callback for the getJson.