# How can I use noscript tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, noscript

When user login with Internet Explorer and user's javascript setting is disabled, I want to show an alert to user. I've tried to use `<noscript>` tags. I've changed my javascript settings (enabled to disabled) for test it but when I try it, nothing displays. How can I do it? Here are my codes below;

```
<script>
  document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>

<p>A browser without support for JavaScript will show the text inside the noscript element.</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shouldn't we use <noscript> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170484/shouldnt-we-use-noscript-tag)

Comment: You could have a hidden div tag with the message inside, if noscript then display the div tag to show the message?

Comment: @NewToJS: How would you plan on showing a hidden div if JS is disabled?

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry i mean have the div set to display, use JS to hide the div.

Comment: If you're really disabling JavaScript as you say, that should work. MelanciaUK's link is useful if you need to handle JavaScript disabled at a more fundamental level, but what you said you did in your question should be showing that `noscript` content.

Comment: It works BUT you have to set `noscript` inside BODY or set the HEAD to `display: block;` (of course, don't!)

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice one. It's because your example its so minimal. The browser automatically wraps the `<script>` and `<noscript>` tags in `<head>`, which means that while the JS executes and writes "Hello world", the `<noscript>` tag gets hidden, because it's in the `<head>`.

If you manually place them in the `<body>` it works fine:

```html
<html><head></head>
<body>
<script>
  document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>

<p>A browser without support for JavaScript will show the text inside the noscript element.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fairly big assumption that the quoted HTML is **all** of the OP's HTML. But if you're right... :-)

Comment: @Frank: That depends entirely on what you're doing with it. If you're trying to display content, then yeah.

Comment: This is true, I just assumed that since the question was about displaying content, he'd probably want it to be in the body element. But you are right, it depends on your application.