# Message when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my project JS is required, so I've added the code below at base layout `_Layout`. But sometimes the message is visible (blinks in the back) while browser rendering.

Any suggestion on how to work better with this message?

The original idea on how to get message if JavaScript disabled is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170503/19210262

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="fixed-left">
    <div id="warningJS" style="display: block;">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <h4>Error: please enable JavaScript</h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="totalBody" style="display:none;">
        //Code here
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let totalBody = document.getElementById('totalBody');
        let warningJS = document.getElementById('warningJS');
        totalBody.style.display = 'block';
        warningJS.style.display = 'none';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) element?

Comment: As I've mentioned, please see the original idea at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170503/19210262

Comment: You could place a `<script>` in the HEAD, and instead of using JS at the end create a Style element that targets `#warningJS` to set the display to `none`

Answer (score 0):

One idea is instead of using JS after the DOM to set the style, target the `#warningJS` with CSS, but create the CSS in code so that it's only run if JS enabled.  Make sure this script is run before the DOM bits that need hiding.

Below is a simple example, I've used the `setTimeout` to simulate a delay to show that there is no flicker.

```html
<script>
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
  style.innerHTML = '#warningJS { display: none; visibility: hidden;}';
</script>

<div id="warningJS" style="display: block;">
  <table style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;">
    <tr>
       <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <h4>Error: please enable JavaScript</h4>
       </td>
    </tr>        
  </table>
</div>

<div id="totalBody" style="display:none;">
        //Code here
</div>

<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const totalBody = document.getElementById('totalBody');
    totalBody.style.display = 'block';
  }, 400);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please make it clear which sections should I add this? I've tried here but seems to be misplaced, since its breaking the page HTML